# Struts 2 + Reading values from the action

Tags: java, struts2

I writing a Struts 2 application. The main operation I'm trying now is to read from the action call a List and display it in the form of a table in the JSP.

I've searched the net and check out a lot of examples, but in vain.

Can someone point out to a good working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/struts2controltags/iterator-tag.shtml

Comment: @leonbloy, that didn't work :( I've already tried it as mentioned earlier

Comment: can't say more without knowing your concrete problem, the above example is simple and typical -and works. i guess you'll have to post your code. your problem is specifically with list/iterators ? you can make it work when just showing just a simple property (scalar field?)?

Comment: @Leonboy, that example need a setter method and then it works fine. Phew!!